# How to properly use Haskell's `parseTimeM` function?

Tags: parsing, haskell, time

Haskell has the function [`parseTimeM`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.5.0.1/docs/Data-Time-Format.html), which replaces the deprecated `parseTime` function. I suppose the reason why the former is preferred over the latter is because it has better flexibility in reporting parse errors. Instead of a `Maybe`, it can call `fail` on the enclosing monad.

So I tried it. First, the deprecated function:

```
> parseTime defaultTimeLocale  "%Y" "2015" :: Maybe UTCTime
Just 2015-01-01 00:00:00 UTC

> parseTime defaultTimeLocale  "%Y" "201x" :: Maybe UTCTime
Nothing
```

Great. As expected. Then, the `Identity` monad:

```
> runIdentity $ parseTimeM  False defaultTimeLocale  "%Y" "2015" :: UTCTime
2015-01-01 00:00:00 UTC

> runIdentity $ parseTimeM  False defaultTimeLocale  "%Y" "201x" :: UTCTime
*** Exception: parseTimeM: no parse of "201x"
```

Also expected, since the `Identity` monad doesn't have an elegant failure mode. But, I expected something different with the `Except` monad, the purpose of which is to gracefully catch errors.

```
> runExcept $ parseTimeM  False defaultTimeLocale  "%Y" "2015" :: Either () UTCTime
Right 2015-01-01 00:00:00 UTC

> runExcept $ parseTimeM  False defaultTimeLocale  "%Y" "201x" :: Either () UTCTime
*** Exception: parseTimeM: no parse of "201y"
```

Why is the exception being thrown here? Shouldn't it return `Left ()` ? How do I parse a time like I think it should, which is to gracefully return an error if the string to be parsed is poorly formatted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Except` is part of the `mtl`, which is a monad transformer library. The usual style with transformers is to define the transformer for some behavior (`ExceptT` in this case) and express the base version as a type synonym:

```
type Except e = ExceptT e Identity
```

So you are probably getting an exception because the `fail` for `Except` has to go through the `Identity` monad at the bottom of its little monad transformer stack.

With `Except e` specifically, how would you implement `fail` for an *arbitrary* type `e`? Since we don't know anything at all about `e`, we can't just conjure up a value of `e` given a string, so `fail` would *have* to give you an exception or loop forever.

All this is a pretty good argument against the `parseTimeM` style of relying on `fail` in the `Monad` class.

Comment: But `parseTime` is now deprecated. Suggestions? Perhaps force `parseTimeM` to return `Maybe UTCTime` and deal with it as before?

Comment: @Ana: Yeah, I think that's the best solution. The less you can rely on `fail` the better.